# Multidimensional arrays with the day as a key

Tags: java, blackberry

```
public void buildArrayForMonth(int month, int year, int numOfDays, JSONArray array){
    JSONObject[][] monthArray = null;

    SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
    SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d");

    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

        try {
            JSONObject event = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String date_full = event.getString("date_full");

            Date date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(date_full));
            int theMonth = Integer.parseInt(monthFormat.format(date)) - 1;
            int theYear = Integer.parseInt(yearFormat.format(date));
            int theDate = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));

            if(theMonth == month && theYear == year){
                System.out.println("This Month" + date_full);
                monthArray[theDate][monthArray[theDate].length] = event; //add event object to the month array and its respective date

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



}
```

I essentially want thedate to be an array containing JSONObjects. My app crashes with what I have now. I'm not sure if you're able to do this. Does Java have anything like push or add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create an array before initialize (I think you are getting NullPointerException in your sample code):

```
monthArray = new JSONObject[32][32];
```

Also, may be HashMap will be more useful for that task.

***UPD*** Ops, and one question, why do you need two dimensional array? I think one dimension is enough.

```
JSONObject monthArray = new JSONObject[32];
monthArray[theDate] = event
```

***UPD2*** And I recommend to use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead of Date and SimpleDateFormat. It is more correct way, for example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getCalendar();
c.setTimeInMillis(HttpDateParser.parse(date_full));
int theMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int theYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int theDate = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

***UPD3***

Update after comments. If more than one event can occurs in one day then you have use HashMap with List as I proposed.

```
HashMap<Integer, List<JSONObject>> monthArray = new HashMap<Integer, List>();
...
if (...) {
    ...
    List l = monthArray.get(theDate);
    if (l == null) {
        l = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();
    }

    l.add(event);

    monthArray.put(theDate, l);
}
```

Comment: There can be more than one event on a particular date.

Comment: @Adam: if there can be more than one event, why would you want to use Date as an index? This is starting to smell funny.

Comment: In that case you need to use HashMap with date as a key and List as a value. In Java you can't dynamically increase length of array like in php for example.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels may be using date as index is not a good idea cause may be we can have two events in the same time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels fixed. I don't have IDE under my fingers right now.

Comment: Thanks Ill try it. I basically want to be able to output an array for the particular month and then to be able to just input the date to retrieve the events.

Comment: Im using jdk 5.0, so maybe that's why that hashmap is not working for me. Ah ok, BlackBerry does not include the hashmap class, but an alternative called multimap.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crazy to use a Date as an array index. Use a `HashMap<Date, JSONObject>` instead for this.

If you want to have one Date be associated with multiple JSONObjects, then perhaps  you want to use a Map that holds a List: `HashMap<Date, List<JSONObject>>`